# Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'ListModelServer[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to access a returned observable, but I get the error that the value does not exist. I want to access the property of the interface

Below are the code

**Interface class**

```
export interface ListModelServer {
    id: Number;
    name: String;
    category: String;
    description: String;
    image: String;
    price: Number;
    quantity: Number;
    images: String;
  }
  
  export interface ListModelServerResponse {
    stores: any;
    count: number;
    list: ListModelServer[];
  }
```

**Here is the service class**

```
 //get all products
  getAllProducts(storeId: Number): Observable<ListModelServer[]> {
    return this.http.get<ListModelServerResponse>(this.url + 'list/' + storeId)
    .pipe(map(response => response.stores
      ));;
  }
```

**In the component, I want to use the fields defined in the interface**

```
export class FoodListComponent implements OnInit {

  list: ListModelServer[];
  
  @ViewChild('quantity') quantityInput!: any;

constructor(private listService: ListService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private cartService: CartService
  
            ) {
}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    //fetch all prod for a particular store
      this.listService.getAllProducts(this.storeId).subscribe(food => {

        this.list = food;
        console.log(this.list);
      });    
   }


  Increase() {
    let value = parseInt(this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value);
    value++;
    if (this.list.quantity >= 1){
      value++;

      if (value > this.list.quantity) {
        // @ts-ignore
        value = this.list.quantity;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }

    this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value = value.toString();
  }

  Decrease() {
    let value = parseInt(this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value);
    value--;
   /*  if (this.list.quantity > 0){
      value--;

      if (value <= 0) {
        // @ts-ignore
        value = 0;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    } */
    this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value = value.toString();
  }
}
```

The error comes from increse() and decrease() methods.

> this.list.quantity

**How do I properly access the properties of an interface in another class??**

Comment: The error is correct. An array doesn't have a `quantity` property. The objects *in* the array probably do have that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working on the list of objects that contains the quantity you have to define on which element you want to increase/decrease the quantity. Check the code below:

```
 Increase(indexOfElementQuantity: number) {
    let value = parseInt(this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value);
    value++;
    if (this.list[indexOfElementQuantity].quantity >= 1){
      value++;

      if (value > this.list[indexOfElementQuantity].quantity) {
        // @ts-ignore
        value = this.list[indexOfElementQuantity].quantity;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }

    this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value = value.toString();
  }
```

of course, you can also pass the id of the particular object as well

```
  Increase(listModelId: number) {
    let value = parseInt(this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value);
    let listModel = this.list.find(x => x.id === listModelId)[0];
    value++;
    if (listModel.quantity >= 1){
      value++;

      if (value > listModel.quantity) {
        // @ts-ignore
        value = listModel.quantity;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }

    this.quantityInput.nativeElement.value = value.toString();
  }
```

Comment: I imagine (your list is an array) you has severals inputs with the same template reference variable `quantity` so you should get all of them using `ViewChildren('quantity') quantities:QuertyList<ElementRef>` -ViewChild only get the First-. You can get the element using `const input=this.quantities.find((_x,index)=>index==indexOfElementQuantity)`